# Single Responsibility in C++ - Should I implement it using friend classes or more accessors?

Tags: c++

I wish to follow the Single Responsibility principle in C++.  However, as I break up classes, it seems that in order for classes to "see" each other, I have the following choices:

1. Add many more accessors for each class
2. Make classes friends of each other
3. Improve the design (maybe the fact that I would have to do 1 or 2 indicates a flaw in my design)

The friend vs. accessors issue has probably been discussed before, but I did not know if one was more advantageous with regard to implementing Single Responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have a group of classes that all need to work together, you should consider *how* they should work together.  If it's via accessor functions or friends, then you're tightly coupling the classes.  It would be difficult in the future to drop in a new class that does something different.  It's also difficult to test the classes since they're all inter-dependent.

Consider creating an interface class(es) that defines how your classes should communicate.  Unless there's some special privileges involved, this interface will also define how anyone else would communicate with them.  This way, you break the classes' inter-dependency.  Any future changes are localized to the class involved.  Nobody else has to change (or maybe even recompile).

Answer (score 4):

I've always thought that rule was BS. Most classes have several responsibilities, and no harm done. Consider a bank account class - it might have the responsibilities:

- maintain client details
- allow for debit & credit transactions
- provide current balance
- report dubious transactions to security

Of course, these responsibilities will probably be implemented using other classes that the account is composed of.

Comment: Depends what you define as responsibility. It is obviously easy to take it too far (as you demonstrate). I would say in this case it is the responsibility of the class to manage an account. You have to use your experience to decide the granularity of what you define as responsibility.

Comment: @Martin I think of responsibilities as things that might appear on a CRC card -  "manage the account" is too vague to be very useful.

Comment: I wouldn't say the rule was BS. In your example, it just says that you should do exactly what you suggest in the last paragraph: delegate the various responsibilities to other classes, leaving the top-level class with the single responsibility of managing them.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Yes 'manage the account' is vague (but I don;t see a spec here). I would start with 'Manage the Account' as the area of responsibility. Then you would need to define what functionality that entails. But since responsibility is a vague term them I fine with a vague definition. At the point of implementation you better have it nailed down though.

Comment: The rule is not BS at all. Responsibilities are hierarchical.  "Manage the Account" includes "open account", "keep track of the balance", "calculate interest", "close account", etc.  These sub-responsibilities should be delegated to separate classes, whose object would be the data members of class `AccountManager`.  If you can break down the class's responsibility into components and give them meaningful names, those should be separate classes.  If you can see logical sections inside a function that need comments, those should be separate functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you *must* expose private data from one class to another, than make the second class a friend.  Creating an accessor for your private data defeats the purpose of making it private in the first place.  The single responsibility principal has no bearing on this.

**Edit**

In response to Dima's comment below, perhaps I went a little too far in saying "the" purpose.  There are, after all, more than one reason to make data members private.  One reason, as Dima notes, is to protect the integrity of the object.  Accessors do accomplish this.

But a second (and more important, in my opinion) reason is to hide the class's implementation details.  Once you've added public accessors, you've lost control over how many other classes reference your class's implementation details.  Over time, this can make it extremely difficult to modify your implementation because of the cascading effect on other classes.

Friend classes, while far from perfect, at least give you strict control over how many classes will be affected by your changes.  Another benefit is that when you do make changes, you know exactly which classes might be affected.  Thus, they're a better option when you must share your class's internals. But the best option of all (of course) is not to not expose implementation details at all.

Comment: I am going to have to go ahead and disagree.  Creating an accessor does not defeat the purpose of making a data member private.  Accessors allow you to define a precise policy for how the data is accessed.  For instance, you may provide a getter but not a setter, thus allowing read-only access.  Or you may provide a member function that sets two data members, but no separate setters, defining a policy that two data members should be changed together.  Friendship, on the other hand, exposes all of the classes private data to another class.  That defeats the purpose of making the data private.

Comment: Interesting comment.  I'll update my answer with my response.

Comment: Once again, I have to disagree. :)  Having accessors does not expose implementation details.  Consider a class `Rectangle` that has a member function `getArea()`.  You still do not know whether `getArea()` simply returns a data member or whether it calculates the area from width and height.  A public accessor is by definition a part of the class' interface, not its internals.  The whole point of keeping the data members private is that you can choose whether or not you provide a accessor. And if you do provide one, you still have the option to change the underlying implementation.

Comment: I guess the crux of the issue here is that friendship lets you control *who* has access to everything, while accessors let you control *what* and *how* everyone can access.  Either you have to give full access to a particular class, or limited access to everyone.  There is no way to give different degrees of access to different classes. From my own experience, however, friendship results in very tight coupling between classes, and often causes more problems than it solves. I am not saying that it should never be used, but that, like almost everything in c++, it should be used very judiciously.

Comment: No offense, Dima, but I think you've missed the point. Friendship does indeed cause problems, but the original question was which is less evil? In the long run, leaking implementation details through your public contract almost always is. But it does depend on the size and complexity of your project.

Answer (score 1):

You also have option 4: add more classes to represent the different roles/interactions between the classes.

That at least falls more in line with the Law of Demeter.